# Color changes cell height in tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, color

The following code shows that a `\color{red}` command increases the height of a tabular cell.
I want to use a switch, not a command as `\textcolor{red}{text}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{0.45\textwidth}}}
\hline
\color{red} header &
header \tabularnewline
\hline
 %
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The cell height will be correct if you insert `\leavevmode` before `\color` for changing into horizontal mode. `\textcolor` does the same internally, it calls `\leavevmode` and then `\color`, additionally it does grouping. So use this as a switch:

```
\leavevmode\color{red} header &
```

If necessary in other places (maybe in moving arguments), consider protecting `\leavevmode`.

```
\protect\leavevmode\color{red}
```

Comment: The `\color` command doesn't switch to LR-mode, since it's useful also between paragraphs; however in a `p` column it defeats the boxing mechanism because when the paragraph starts, as soon as TeX scans the `h` in "header", the vertical list is not empty. Issuing `\leavevmode` cures the problem by starting a paragraph itself.

Comment: @egreg: thanks for the additional explanation!

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{2}{p{0.45\textwidth}}}
\hline
\color{red} header &
header \tabularnewline
\hline
 %
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]