# Color lines tabularx add padding?

Tags: spacing, color, tabularx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color changes cell height in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31547/color-changes-cell-height-in-tabular)

The following latex table contains two rows. The rows are identical, except for the greeen color in the first cell in the second row:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X| }
  \hline
  \texttt{re.match('go.', 'gob')}                       & 2  & 3  & 4  \\
  \hline
  \color{ForestGreen}{\texttt{re.match('go.', 'gob')}}  & 2  & 3  & 4  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

The color appears to add some padding space above it:
[image]

When the color is removed, the spacing is normal again:

[image]

**Why does cell color affect table spacing?**

[Original file in github](https://gist.github.com/3930121).

Comment: I am not sure about the padding that the command `\color{<color>}{<text>}` does but `\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\texttt{re.match('go.', 'gob')}}` seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this really answers your question. But if you want to make the table behave normally with text color then you can use `\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\texttt{re.match('go.', 'gob')}}`. My guess is that with the `\color` command, the color is extended to the whole box containing your text. Try for instance `\colorbox` command as you can see in the attached picture.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\raggedright
\footnotesize

\section{Meta characters}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X| }
  \hline
  \texttt{re.match('go.', 'gob')} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \hline
  \textcolor{ForestGreen}{\texttt{re.match('go.', 'gob')}} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \hline
  \color{ForestGreen}{\texttt{re.match('go.', 'gob')}} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \hline
  \colorbox{ForestGreen}{\texttt{re.match('go.', 'gob')}} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]